# Unable to access $_GET variable after .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I have a category page that lists all of the items in the database via a loop.

Each item in the category page links to individual product pages (product.php), which is in the same directory as the category page. The product page is dynamic and its content is dependent on the value of the $_GET variable:

The link from main category page that generates the product.php page is:

```
<a href="product.php?subject=<?php echo urlencode($list_savory["product_name"]); ?>">
```

The resulting product.php URL's were displaying as:

```
shop/popcorn/product.php?subject=Bacon+and+Cheddar+Popcorn
```

I added the following .htaccess code to remove the query string and replace the '+' with dashes:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !no-redir [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)subject=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/product.php$ $1/%2? [NC]

RewriteRule ^([^+\s]+)(?:[+\s]+)([^+\s]+)((?:[+\s]+).*)$ $1-$2$3 [DPI,N]
RewriteRule ^([^+\s]+)(?:[+\s]+)([^+\s]+)$ $1-$2 [R=301,DPI,L]
```

After the .htacess code, the resulting URL's format as

```
shop/popcorn/Bacon-and-Cheddar-Popcorn
```

The .htaccess code works perfectly to reformat the URL's, but I lost access to the $_GET variable so the pages aren't loading correctly. How can I modify the .htaccess code so that the $_GET variable is passed?

Comment: you're... removing the get variables. they aren't going to be passed. usually rewrites are done in the opposite direction.

Comment: You're doing it wrong : This is known as `routing mechanism` and should be done purely using PHP itself via `MVC/MVP/MVVM` patterns.

Comment: And also, since you use `mod_rewrite` to access variables, the `$_GET` will no longer work the way you expect. Instead, you should write a parser for `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Comment: Can I modify the conditional on the product.php page to check for the $_SERVER (as opposed to the $_GET) variable and still use the .htaccess code above to format the URLs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the query string, don't add it in your content:

```
<a href="<?php echo urlencode($list_savory["product_name"]); ?>">
```

resulting in a URL that displays as:

```
/shop/popcorn/Bacon+and+Cheddar+Popcorn
```

Then in your htaccess file, you need to internally route it to `product.php` and pass the product name as the "subject":

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^shop/popcorn/(.*)$ /shop/popcorn/product.php?subject=$1 [L,B,NC]
```

Not sure what your other rules are supposed to do, I supposed you can append them somewhere appropriate. The rules above *need to be in the htaccess file in your document root*.

Comment: I updated the question to show the resulting URL that I am trying to achieve. Does your code take into account that I also want to strip the 'product' reference?

Comment: @Chris just remove all of the "/product" path nodes. (I edited them out of the answer)

Comment: Updated the working code and the URL's are formatting properly, but I am receiving a 404 server error ('The requested URL /shop/popcorn/product.php was not found on this server.') Could the fact that I am working locally be causing this?

Comment: @Chris if there is no `/shop/popcorn/product.php` file? Where is it? The rule's target needs to point to it.

Comment: Also, I should note that the product.php page is currently dependent on a conditional that checks to see if the $_GET['subject'] variable isset and matches a mysqli database query. The product.php page is in the exact directory that your .htaccess rule references.

Comment: @Chris so you can goto `http://your.host/shop/popcorn/product.php` page and not get a 404? (or at least get a page not found returned by the product.php script as opposed to apache)

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention two very important items: 1) I am working locally, and 2) I have the site contained in a folder 'campbells'. I can indeed access the page http://localhost/campbells/shop/popcorn/product.php, but nothing loads as the conditional isn't being satisfied.

Comment: @Chris Remove the leading `/` from `/shop/popcorn/product.php`, change the rewrite base from `/` to `/campbells/`

Comment: your code worked perfectly. The issue was stemming from how the remaining .htaccess code was formatting the spaces in the $_GET["subject"] variable. Once I figured that out, I just peformed a simple str_replace on the variable prior to passing it through the conditional. THANKS!